# Bigquery split rows by timestamp of event

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In Google BigQuery, I have a list of events in a single support session which are tagged by event names. Each support issue `resolved_time` is the timestamp of the `resolved` event. Each issue `start_time` is the first occurrence of either of the events `message`, `pending`, or `unresolved` either at the absolute beginning of the session or following a resolved tag.

In other words, the state of the conversation is either open or resolved. The state becomes open with the first occurrence of a `message`, `pending`, or `unresolved` event, and is closed with a `resolved` event.

Currently I have the table with `timestamp` and `event_name` only. Would like to join in `start_time` and `resolved_time`.

In the example below, this results in 4 separate support issues. Three being resolved with `resolved` events and the last being unresolved since it is not closed with a `resolved` event.

| timestamp | event_name | start_time | resolved_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-15 20:27:59 UTC | unresolved | 2021-01-15 20:27:59 UTC | 2021-01-20 19:31:37 UTC |
| 2021-01-16 03:02:46 UTC | message | 2021-01-15 20:27:59 UTC | 2021-01-20 19:31:37 UTC |
| 2021-01-20 19:31:37 UTC | resolved | 2021-01-15 20:27:59 UTC | 2021-01-20 19:31:37 UTC |
| 2021-01-21 00:13:43 UTC | pending | 2021-01-21 00:13:43 UTC | 2021-01-23 23:38:46 UTC |
| 2021-01-23 23:38:46 UTC | resolved | 2021-01-21 00:13:43 UTC | 2021-01-23 23:38:46 UTC |
| 2021-01-24 00:38:17 UTC | message | 2021-01-24 00:38:17 UTC | 2021-01-24 02:19:44 UTC |
| 2021-01-24 00:42:31 UTC | unresolved | 2021-01-24 00:38:17 UTC | 2021-01-24 02:19:44 UTC |
| 2021-01-24 02:19:44 UTC | resolved | 2021-01-24 00:38:17 UTC | 2021-01-24 02:19:44 UTC |
| 2021-01-25 15:55:50 UTC | message | 2021-01-25 15:55:50 UTC | NULL |
| 2021-01-25 15:59:55 UTC | unresolved | 2021-01-25 15:55:50 UTC | NULL |

```
WITH sample_table AS (
    SELECT  TIMESTAMP("2021-01-15 20:27:59") `timestamp` , "unresolved" event_name UNION ALL
    SELECT  TIMESTAMP("2021-01-16 03:02:46") , "message"  UNION ALL
    SELECT  TIMESTAMP("2021-01-20 19:31:37") , "resolved"  UNION ALL
    SELECT  TIMESTAMP("2021-01-21 00:13:43") , "pending"  UNION ALL
    SELECT  TIMESTAMP("2021-01-23 23:38:46") , "resolved" UNION ALL
    SELECT  TIMESTAMP("2021-01-24 00:38:17") , "message" UNION ALL
    SELECT  TIMESTAMP("2021-01-24 00:42:31") , "unresolved" UNION ALL
    SELECT  TIMESTAMP("2021-01-24 02:19:44") , "resolved" UNION ALL
    SELECT  TIMESTAMP("2021-01-25 15:55:50") , "message" UNION ALL
    SELECT  TIMESTAMP("2021-01-25 15:59:55") , "unresolved" )

SELECT * FROM sample_table
ORDER BY timestamp ASC
```

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: Does old issue always close before new issue open?
Is multiple events with the same name possible per single issue?

Comment: Two support issues cannot be opened at a same time. So the state is either Open or Closed. I'll clarify in the question.

Comment: I don't get it.  First, what results do you want?  Second, you have two "resolved" records, 3 "message", 1 "pending", and 2 "unresolved".  How does this turn into 4 support issues?  The question is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving `MAX` and `MIN` could be a good fit here:

```
WITH sample_table AS (
    SELECT  TIMESTAMP("2021-01-15 20:27:59") timestamp, "unresolved" event_name UNION ALL
    SELECT  TIMESTAMP("2021-01-16 03:02:46"), "message" UNION ALL
    SELECT  TIMESTAMP("2021-01-20 19:31:37"), "resolved" UNION ALL
    SELECT  TIMESTAMP("2021-01-21 00:13:43"), "pending" UNION ALL
    SELECT  TIMESTAMP("2021-01-23 23:38:46"), "resolved" UNION ALL
    SELECT  TIMESTAMP("2021-01-24 00:38:17"), "message" UNION ALL
    SELECT  TIMESTAMP("2021-01-24 00:42:31"), "unresolved" UNION ALL
    SELECT  TIMESTAMP("2021-01-24 02:19:44"), "resolved" UNION ALL
    SELECT  TIMESTAMP("2021-01-25 15:55:50"), "message" UNION ALL
    SELECT  TIMESTAMP("2021-01-25 15:59:55"), "unresolved"
)
SELECT 
  *, 
  MAX(IF(prev_event='resolved' OR prev_event IS NULL, timestamp, NULL)) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS start_time,
  MIN(IF(event_name='resolved', timestamp, NULL)) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS resolved_time,
FROM (
  SELECT 
    *,
    LAG(event_name) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp) as prev_event,
  FROM sample_table
)
```

[image]

Comment: That works perfectly. I didn't think of doing it by adding conditionals to a window function. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To be honest I didn't understand what you want, however I grouped the messages in an array and also calculated the status of the ticket.

```
WITH sample_table AS (
    SELECT  TIMESTAMP("2021-01-15 20:27:59") `timestamp` , "unresolved" event_name,  TIMESTAMP("2021-01-15 20:27:59") start_time, TIMESTAMP("2021-01-20 19:31:37") resolved_time UNION ALL
    SELECT  TIMESTAMP("2021-01-16 03:02:46") , "message",  TIMESTAMP("2021-01-15 20:27:59"), TIMESTAMP("2021-01-20 19:31:37") UNION ALL
    SELECT  TIMESTAMP("2021-01-20 19:31:37") , "resolved",  TIMESTAMP("2021-01-15 20:27:59"), TIMESTAMP("2021-01-20 19:31:37") UNION ALL
    SELECT  TIMESTAMP("2021-01-21 00:13:43") , "pending",  TIMESTAMP("2021-01-21 00:13:43"), TIMESTAMP("2021-01-23 23:38:46") UNION ALL
    SELECT  TIMESTAMP("2021-01-23 23:38:46") , "resolved",  TIMESTAMP("2021-01-21 00:13:43"), TIMESTAMP("2021-01-23 23:38:46") UNION ALL
    SELECT  TIMESTAMP("2021-01-24 00:38:17") , "message",  TIMESTAMP("2021-01-24 00:38:17"), TIMESTAMP("2021-01-24 02:19:44") UNION ALL
    SELECT  TIMESTAMP("2021-01-24 00:42:31") , "unresolved",  TIMESTAMP("2021-01-24 00:38:17"), TIMESTAMP("2021-01-24 02:19:44") UNION ALL
    SELECT  TIMESTAMP("2021-01-24 02:19:44") , "resolved",  TIMESTAMP("2021-01-24 00:38:17"), TIMESTAMP("2021-01-24 02:19:44") UNION ALL
    SELECT  TIMESTAMP("2021-01-25 15:55:50") , "message",  TIMESTAMP("2021-01-25 15:55:50"), NULL UNION ALL
    SELECT  TIMESTAMP("2021-01-25 15:59:55") , "unresolved",  TIMESTAMP("2021-01-25 15:55:50"), NULL
)
SELECT start_time, resolved_time, 
    array_agg(struct(timestamp, event_name) order by timestamp) as events,
    CASE 
        WHEN MAX('resolved' = event_name) THEN 'resolved'
        ELSE 'open'
    END as status
FROM sample_table
group by 1,2
order by 1,2
```